# Too many Join Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

First of all I am going to explain what's going on in my application:
I have 4 models. Company, Student, Volunteer and BusinessSegment and their relations are the following:

**company.rb**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :business_segments`

**student.rb**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :business_segments`

**volunteer.rb**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :business_segments`

**business_segment.rb**

`has_and_belongs_to_many :students`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteers`

`has_and_belongs_to_many :companies`

**How it's going to work:**

Admin user will create some business segments and each of these users (company, student, volunteer) will be able to choose some of the created business segments.

In this way I will have to create 3 different join tables (business_segments_students, business_segments_volunteers, business_segments_companies)

Is there any other way to do this ?

P.S I looked up polymorphic association but it doesn't seem to work in this case!

Comment: At the penalty of data redundancy and nullable data, you can use Table Per Hierarchy instead of Table Per Type or Table Per Concrete Class.  This will reduce the number of tables... but why are you concerned about the joins?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to avoid creating 3 different tables and do something easier. Maybe there is no other way, just asking :)

Comment: Three join tables is the conventional way to do this. I think it's fair to say that any other solution would be *more* difficult, not less - that's what happens when you design against convention, rather than with it.